# Is it possible to test Angular without Karma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm pretty new to angular& we already have a working rails-stack with the [jasmine-rails.gem](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails) - the tests that come with the example-app are not working, as

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

fails with a `Can't find variable: module` - and I got no idea where `module` and `inject` are supposed to be defined: Does anyone have an idea how to set up angular-tests to run standalone/outside of karma?

Answer (score 2):

They come with `angular-mocks.js`, include that.

Get it at http://code.angularjs.org/

Comment: totally made my day: adding the mocks got me over the initial hump, got the rest to run piece by piece - thx!